# Is there a way to get the OSM nodes from a route generated by yournavigation

Tags: neo4j, routes, openstreetmap

yournavigation.org generates routes between two nodes in openstreetmap data. The info returned by the API includes length, traveltime and (OSM) nodes. Is there a way to retrieve all these nodes the algorithm found?

I would like to import these nodes into Neo4j for all the routes leading from the addresses of a group of people to one single target location in order to determine where their ways meet.

Example: First route [from Zürichbergstrasse 22 to Rämistrasse 71 in Zürich](http://yournavigation.org/?flat=47.3730469&flon=8.5531747789738&tlat=47.374725691823&tlon=8.5495677145362&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik), second route [from Freiestrasse 27 to Rämistrasse 71 in Zürich](http://yournavigation.org/?flat=47.37133045&flon=8.5544611068646&tlat=47.374725691823&tlon=8.5495677145362&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik). The two routes obviously meet at Gloriastrasse, but how can I retrieve this node? I would start backwards from the target and find the last node the two routes have in common. For this, I would like to load all nodes yournavigation found into Neo4j, and the rest would be very straight forward.

Thank you for any hints and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the GPX export and check where the GPX tracks will meet. If you need to obtain the name of the street then just perform a reverse geocoding request for the first common track point, for example by using [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

Comment: I think the GPX track points are indeed the nodes I need. Thank you very much!